# tag [writedata] shouldn't be written

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [writedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writedata) tag seems to be used for cases where data is written to a file, loosely used throughout different languages, not pointing to a singular function/method.

There's no tag wiki/summary either.

Immediately looking at the question, I see [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) questions. There's only 18 questions using the tag, so it shouldn't be a big deal.

I'm proposing the tag be burninated.

Comment: The tag is now empty, it should be removed when the daily empty tag removal script runs then no users with less than 1500 rep will be able to use it.